# OnPreviewTextInput not always providing Text

Tags: wpf, ime, cjk

We have an existing application we are trying to replace with a new WPF application.

One of the controls we use in the legacy application has a specialized behavior where the control redirects any text input by the user to be processed externally. After which the result is updated programmatically back into the control. (the control behaves similarly to a read-only `TextBox` in that the user is not allowed edit text directly in the control; any text the user types is redirected before it is shown in the control)

We settled on using the `OnPreviewTextInput` event to redirect `e.Text` and mark the event as `e.Handled`. This worked using English input as well as the Microsoft Japanese IME. But when we tried using the Microsoft Korean IME, `e.Text` comes through as an empty string...

Any thoughts on why it would work for Japanese, but not for Korean?